# Analog (PAL) Frame Grabber capable of arround 4 fps

Tags: video, hardware

I have a video camera with a external trigger. I have been experimenting with the external trigger and it looks like I'm ready to grab some frames.

I'm new on this field of hobby, and therefor I have no clue what to look for. Are there any consumer frame grabbers with flexible OR low frame rate?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you are asking about.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you want a slow frame rate?  PAL is 25 frames per second.

Comment: It's a hobby project I'm working on.
All I'm asking for, is a frame grabber capable of 4fps

Comment: I get that it is a hobby project, but it sounds like you may be going about it the wrong way.  It's a very unusual request that would likely require specialized hardware as nothing runs at that slow of a rate?  If you are trying to do a time lapse for example, there are better options available to you.